# check if a string is in regex requirement

Tags: java, regex

Hi I am trying to check if an input string is corrected or not however i run into some issues

```
 String pattern = "[a-zA-z\\s]+";
 String string="Richard Lin";
 System.out.println(string.matches(pattern));
```

this will print out true however if my string is string= "Richard Lin      " (more spaces) it still returns true. is there a way to detect this ???
I dont want to check if there is number in it and my string contain more than 2 elements.

Comment: Do you really have `[a-zA-z\\s]+`?  With two `z`?

Comment: you have an error in you syntax near `A-z`, try with `"[a-zA-Z\\s]+"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to accept strings like `"a Bcd"` `"Ab dcE f"` and so on you can use

```
[a-zA-Z]+(\\s[a-zA-Z]+)+
```

- `[a-zA-Z]+` will match words like `"a"` `"xYZ"` `"something"`
- `\\s[a-zA-Z]+` will match words with space before it
- `(\\s[a-zA-Z]+)+` will match continuous words with space before them, like `" one"`, `" one two"`, `" some sentence with lot of words that have space at start"`.

Comment: can you explain a bit more plz ?

Answer (score 3):

You could just match the individual words:

```
String pattern = "\\p{Alpha}{3,} \\p{Alpha}{3,}";
```

Comment: `\w` includes digits and underscore - that's not really the same as what the OP's looking for.  It's the right general idea, though - don't match the spaces as part of the name groups.

Comment: i dont want to check if it has number in it only character

Comment: and i want to have more than 2 elements inside the string